# Postgres query different COUNT and ROW_NUMBER()

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have a table messages with the following columns

```
group_id BIGINT, 
user_id BIGINT, 
message_date timestamp
```

For the right user_id I would like to be able to count the total rows with that user_id, the distinct groups with that user_id, and considering a leaderboard made by the count of user_id, the position too.

I tried this query

```
SELECT main.total_m, main.group_number, main.pos 
FROM (
    SELECT user_id, COUNT(group_id) AS group_number, COUNT(user_id) AS total_m,  
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY COUNT(user_id)
            ORDER BY COUNT(user_id) DESC
            ) AS pos 
    FROM messages
    WHERE message_date > date_trunc('week', now())
    GROUP BY user_id, group_id
) AS main 
WHERE user_id = %s
```

But I don't get the result I would like to have. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Provide sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The power of "sample data" and "expected result" is it enables others to answer efficiently. The following is a complete guess, but perhaps it will prompt you to prepare a "[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)" (MCVE)

The detials below can be accessed at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c43ea/3)

**PostgreSQL 9.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Messages
    (USER_ID int, GROUP_ID int, MESSAGE_DATE timestamp)
;

INSERT INTO Messages
    (USER_ID, GROUP_ID, MESSAGE_DATE)
VALUES
    (1, 7, '2017-09-01 10:00:00'),
    (1, 6, '2017-09-02 10:00:00'),
    (1, 5, '2017-09-03 10:00:00'),
    (1, 4, '2017-09-04 10:00:00'),
    (1, 7, '2017-09-05 10:00:00'),
    (2, 6, '2017-09-01 10:00:00'),
    (2, 5, '2017-09-02 10:00:00'),
    (2, 7, '2017-09-03 10:00:00'),
    (2, 6, '2017-09-04 10:00:00'),
    (2, 4, '2017-09-05 10:00:00'),
    (2, 8, '2017-09-11 10:00:00')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select
      user_id
    , num_grps
    , num_msgs
    , dense_rank() over(order by num_grps DESC, num_msgs DESC, max_date DESC, user_id) rnk
from (
    select
          user_id
        , count(distinct group_id) num_grps
        , count(*)                 num_msgs
        , max(message_date)        max_date
    from messages
    group by
          user_id
    ) d
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c43ea/3/0)**:

```
| user_id | num_grps | num_msgs | rnk |
|---------|----------|----------|-----|
|       2 |        5 |        6 |   1 |
|       1 |        4 |        5 |   2 |
```

Comment: thank you your answer is perfect. It really solve my problem but you miss a part from my query: the WHERE user_id = %s

i have to get the set for a specific user_id.
i tried to add it in your version at the end doing
`WHERE d.user_id = %s` but then the `rnk` column is always 1 with every id

Comment: maybe i should make your query as a subquery and i add the where to the parent query?

Comment: As you work through this, please then consider what it must be like to answer a question where the end target isn't known..... You will need to run this whole query before you can get the correct rank of an individual user. Now you need to consider the efficency of that and how often you really want to do this etc.but those considerations are well outside the scope of this question.

Comment: ok i made an outer query and your query is in `FROM` of mine, then i put the WHERE clause on the outer query i added. It works! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at just the inner query, I see this in the select:

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(group_id), ...
```

But this in the GROUP BY:

```
GROUP BY user_id, group_id
```

Put those together, and you'll never have a `COUNT()` result of anything other than `1`, because each `group_id` has it's own group. It works for the same for `total_m` column.

Comment: So how could i get the expected result? No way to do it in one query?